# Неверное отображение изображений и блоков

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Имеется вот такой html/css код с 2 блоками:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
}

ul li {
  padding: 11px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li>ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul li a {
    display: none;
  }
}

.main_content {
  display: inline;
}

.html5div {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.html5 {
  padding-top: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.css3div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: right;
  background: blue;
  display: block;
}

.css3 {
  padding-top: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_content">
  <div class="html5div">
    <a href="#"><img class="html5" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="css3div">
    <a href="#"><img class="css3" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg/363px-CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как установить одинаковый размер фона и адаптивный размер изображений?

Comment: неверное это какое? какое верное? что вы хотите получить? что вы для этого сделали? что именно не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.html5div {
   max-width: 300px;
   height: auto;
   float: left;
}

.css3div {
   max-width: 300px;
   height: auto;
   float: left;
}

img {
   width: 100%;
}
```